# Quickblox: Unable to sign up with the same username on two different apps

Tags: quickblox

I have two apps set up on my quickblox account. I have the login "test0" in the first one. When I try to sign up with the login "test0" on the other app, I get a 422 Unprocessable Entity error.

If this is just how Quickblox is set up, I'll have to do a good deal of refactoring so I just want to be sure that there is no other option to allow for the same login on two different apps in quickblox.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Users that you have on one Quickblox application will are not shared to any other Quickblox applications.

Comment: This is true, but I am still unable to sign up with a given username if it is already in use on another application.

Comment: Yes, thats the issue of the current server architecture. It will be addressed in a next versions.